# How do I reliably get two elements' dimensions on page load

Tags: jquery

Say I have a "container" element that has `overflow:auto`, with a "contents" div inside. The container's height is a percentage of the window height, and the content could be any height:

```
<div id="container">// Height dependent on window size
    <div id="content">
    // Arbitrary amount of content here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS as requested - please note in my "real world" scenario, the content element is actually a table, with rules as below:

```
#container {
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto
}

#content {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

What I want to do is check whether the content's height exceeds the container's and do something if true.

However, if I simply do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var containerH = $('#container').outerHeight();
    var contentH = $('#content').outerHeight();
    if ( contentH > containerH ) {
        // If the content's too big, do things...
    };
});
```

the if statement never runs, because the two heights are always calculated as being equal - even when I *know* that it is not the case. Subsequent checks always reveal the actual dimensions.

So I thought: maybe the elements aren't finished rendering (I'm using @font-face to style text in the elements - perhaps I need to wait for that to complete) and I then tried to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var container = $('#container');
    var content = $('#content');

    function getProperHeight(el){
        var height = el.load(function(){
            var h = this.outerHeight();
            return h;
        });
        return height;
    };

    var containerH = getProperHeight(container);
    var contentH = getProperHeight(content);

    console.log( containerH + ' ' + contentH )

};
```

which is the closest I got using the `load()` method, but I get [object Object] for both expected values.

In short - how can I get the actual rendered dimensions of the two elements?

Comment: I think your problem is that your are doing this calculation on $(document).ready(). You should try placing this code on a button click event and see if it works.

Comment: I see the logic in what you're suggesting, but this is required to work on page load. Getting the heights on a user event is trivial, as the elements are almost certainly loaded by that point.

Comment: I was just saying for you to try to see if it works on a button click. If it does work on the button click the problem is that at the time $(document).ready() is called the DOM hasn't actually processed your CSS to make the calculations the way you want. If this is the case you could set the CSS on the javascript or explore other event possibilities.

Comment: could we see the CSS?

Answer (score -1):

You could something like this...

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="listingNav">
    <a id="back">Back </a>
    <div id="paginationNav"></div>
    <a id="next"> Next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    // Arbitrary amount of content here
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
  overflow:hidden;  
}
```

Javascript

```
//set how tall you want you container to be
var divHeight = 624;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    //get the height of the container without styles
    var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
    //then add styles to the container
    $('#content').css('height', divHeight + 'px');
    //find out how many pages there will be
    var divPages = Math.ceil(contentHeight / divHeight);
    //loop through and create the page # anchors
    for(var i = 1; i <= divPages; i++)
    {
        $("#paginationNav").append('<a id="' + i + '" onclick="javascript:goToPage(this)">' + i + '</a>');
    } 
    //wrap every in #content with a div with the class of .content
    $('#content').children().wrapAll('<div class="content"/>');
    //program the paganation effect for next
    $('#next').click(function() {
        var current = ($('.content').css('margin-top') || '0px');
        if((current.substring(0,current.length-2) - divHeight) > -contentHeight)
        {
            $('.content').css('margin-top',current.substring(0,current.length-2) - $('#listingContainer').height() + 'px');
        }
    });
    //program the paganation effect for back
    $('#back').click(function() {
        var current = ($('.content').css('margin-top') || '0px');
        if(current.substring(0,current.length-2) < 0)
        {
            $('.content').css('margin-top',(current.substring(0,current.length-2) - -$('#listingContainer').height()) + 'px');
        }
    });
});
//program the paganation effect for each of the page # anchors
function goToPage(page)
{
    $('.content').css('margin-top', -((divHeight * page.id) - divHeight));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Oh..... and this is using jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Thank you the thorough post - but I'm not sure it's all relevant to my question. I want to measure the heights rather than set them, as your example seems to do. Also, I'm not sure why you've included pagination techniques - it's interesting, but I'm not really asking for that in the question.

Comment: well you said you wanted to compare the heights of the two div and then do something based on the comparison. The pagination thing was just the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: And from what I can see the styles you are using for `#container` makes it as big as the page or to put it another way as big as it needs to be which means `#content` and `#container` will always be the same height. To do a comparison you need to set the height of `#container` to something more definite whether that be in px or %.

Comment: `#container` is 100% of its parent's height, but this doesn't mean it can't be measured in pixels; any browser console will give the exact height. And `#contents` has a variable height that can and (more pertinently) will exceed the container's - child element dimensions are not necessarily limited by their parents'.

Comment: With the styles you have now `#container` will never be smaller then `#content`. you need to set `#container`'s height to definite value like 90% or 600px. If you leave it at 100% `#container` will be as big as its parent and if the parent doesn't have a set height it will be as big as its parent and so until you hit the `body` tag.

Comment: My second sentence states "The container's height is a percentage of the window height", i.e. its height _is_ defined. I purposely didn't include a lot of other markup and CSS for the sake of brevity. I also stated that "the two heights are always calculated as being equal - even when I know that it is not the case. Subsequent checks always reveal the actual dimensions" - I took care to ensure that the issue was as described (unable to determine dimensions on page load) and not that they _are_ the same.

Comment: From the code you gave, `#container` will always be equal to or greater then `#content`, it will never be smaller. So you either have a problem with some of the CSS you are not showing us or the javascript you are not showing us. So what I am saying is you are not including enough code.